# How to connect Cloud SQL Server via external python program?

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql

So I am trying to communicate to a Google Cloud SQL Server that I have created with an external python program that I have written in VS Code but I don't know where to begin. Any help will be useful.

Comment: What's the actual question? How to connect to a Google cloud database in general? How to connect to SQL Server using Python? Those are two very different things. [Connecting using a database client from a local machine or Compute Engine ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-ip) shows how to connect to a Google-hosted database. If you can't connect using a database client you won't be able to connect using Python either.

Comment: Microsoft's [PyODBC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) shows how to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc and the SQL Server ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) to manage your connections to Cloud SQL. It supports the `pytds` driver and should help resolve your troubles for connecting to a SQL Server instance from a Python application.

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector
import sqlalchemy

# configure Cloud SQL Python Connector properties
def getconn() ->:
    conn = connector.connect(
        "PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE",
        "pytds",
        user="YOUR_USER",
        password="YOUR_PASSWORD",
        db="YOUR_DB"
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool to re-use connections
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mssql+pytds://localhost",
    creator=getconn,
)

# query or insert into Cloud SQL database
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

For more detailed examples and additional params refer to the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) of the repository.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can be inspired by this :[Python django](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#run-locally)
"Run the app on your local computer"

Comment: [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) aren't good answers. In this case the linked article has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).